# Increased font-size causes ul menu to be misaligned

Tags: html, css

As demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9SG5/), I've built a fixed menu using unordered lists and a lot of css. I've also included a button with a custom class that redirects back to the frontpage and made it a litter bigger using font-size: 130%. By using line-height: 0; I was able to force all buttons to be the same height. Unfortunately, somehow an extra pixel of height is added to the menu and the big button sticks to the top, while the rest of the buttons stick to the bottom. Apart from seriously triggering OCD, it looks plain ugly when hovering, so I'd like to fix it. I am at a dead end and cannot solve this by myself, so I would like to ask anyone to help me out.

Thanks in advance!

```
li.menu-titel {
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: lighter;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple format all your `li` with `display:inline-block` (instead of `inline`),

*or* remove the `vertical-align:top;`.

Comment: Ah yes! vertical-align:top; already was a result of a few futile attempts, but substituting display:inline-block for display:inline in combination with vertical-align: top did the trick. Thank you!